# Why doesn't a image change to a gif correctly with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, gif

I am making a game with a car that turns into an explosion when you click it. (Check it out at https://clickersandbeyond.com); I have tested the explosion in html and it works just fine, but when you click the car it changes to the gif correctly but it is stopped at a single frame.

Any help would be appreciated and here is my code

```js
if(carClicks == 1){
    document.getElementById("image").src = "../Images/explosion.gif";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link isn't changing the car image for me, but gifs do display in img tags. See below for a very simple example:

```js
 document.getElementById("image").src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBv4T.gif";
```

```html
<img id="image"/>
```

I would try a different image to see if that changes anything.